# Laravel Eloquent Eager Loading assumes incorrect pivot table column name

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables in Laravel 5.4. Orders and Product which are joined by a many-to-many relationship

I'm trying to fetch all the orders together with the associated products like so:

```
$orders = Orders::with('products')->get();
```

My Order Model has this set up as

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')
        ->withPivot('qty')
        ->withTimeStamps();
}
```

When I output the log I get the following error message:

```
Next Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'order_product.order_order_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `products`.*, `order_product`.`order_order_id` as `pivot_order_order_id`, `order_product`.`product_product_id` as `pivot_product_product_id`, `order_product`.`qty` as `pivot_qty`, `order_product`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`, `order_product`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at` from `products` inner join `order_product` on `products`.`product_id` = `order_product`.`product_product_id` where `order_product`.`order_order_id` in (66, 67, 70, 72, 73, 74) and `products`.`deleted_at` is null) in /home/vagrant/Projects/vcc-backoffice/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:647
```

The issue is that Laravel is looking for a table in the Pivot called "**order_order_id**" which doesn't exist. I haven't declared the column to be called that.  My pivot table columns are called "**order_id**" and "**product_id**"

I don't know how Laravel assumes the pivot table names. Is there a way to specifically declare the column names in the pivot? Or have I made a mistake in my naming conventions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit **Order** Model and try following code :

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','order_product','order_id','product_id')
        ->withPivot('qty')
        ->withTimeStamps();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have two model named `Order` & `Product` and many_to_many relationship between them and their database table like `orders` & `products` then Laravel will search for a pivot table named `order_product` (model name in alphabetic order and joined by '_' ).
`order_product` table will composed of two columns `order_id`,`product_id` . This is the basic naming convention for pivot table in a nutshell :) .